# C returning garbage value for length greater than 3

Tags: c

I have a main function that has to receive a string.

```
main()
{
    char *c = fun();
}

char* fun()
{
    char a[] = "hello";
    return a;
}
```

The problem is that if I return string of lenght 3 or less, then everything is good. If I return string of length > 3, then I receive garbage value along with the string. Why is that ?

Comment: @H2CO3 - probably somewhere between 'my FP compares are not working' and 'how can I stop my thread'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `a` is local to `fun()`, and so goes out of scope (and out of existence) when you return. The fact that is works for any case is pure luck. You could make `a` static, or dynamically allocated, or fix it in ohter ways.

Answer (score 3):

You return a pointer to a local variable. The variable is stack-allocated, and it is destroyed when the function exits. Using such pointer is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* fun()
{
    char a[] = "hello";
    return a;
}
```

Array `a` has automatic storage duration. At the end of the function the array object `a` is destroyed. This means the pointer becomes invalid at the exit of the function and any use of it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an automatic variable, which is a big no-no. That it works at all is an accident of the implementation.